# How to name a Class whose only purpose is to return a Boolean

Tags: c#, .net, naming-conventions

I have a class whose sole responsibility is to tell me if a remote command has returned `yes` or `no` and I'm not sure how to name it.

More specifically, my application is a front end for a collection of Linux commands.  We communicate with Linux via SSH.  Each business operation (ex. GetItem, CreateItem, GetItemCount, etc) maps to a **Command** class.  Each **Command** class derives from a base SSH **Command** class that handles all the communication details.

My latest **Command** is to check if a remote file is of a certain Type (let's call it a Doodle type).  To achieve this the remote file is run through a remote program and if that program returns 1 or more lines on the console then the file is a Doodle.

Now I'm struggling with how to name my class.

If it were a method and not a class I would call it `IsDoodle`.  But because the class involves Getting information from a remote location and also derives from a **Command** base class, I'm tempted to use `GetIsDoodleCommand`.

Any thoughts?

#### Update

While I understand the suggestion of using `CommandResult` I don't think it fits in with the existing pattern we use.  Or maybe I don't understand!  Either way, I think my original question could benefit from a few more details:

- The base class is abstract, and has an abstract `Execute` method
- The derived **Command** classes are responsible for implementing `Execute`
- The base class is Generic (`public class CommandBase<T>`)
- The return type of `Execute` is `T`

So typical usage of the derived class would be:

```
var nameMeCommand = new NameMeCommand();
bool isDoodle = nameMeCommand.Execute();

var getItemCommand = new GetItemCommand();
Item myItem = getItemCommand.Execute();
```

Comment: `CommandResult`

Comment: You should name it `CommandResult` as Odded said, from there you can expose property `IsDoodle`, later if you need extra information with your class you can have those in other properties.

Comment: How about CommandGetDoodle as class name and with property IsDoodle or IsDoodleType.

Comment: FileTypeCommand? Sidenote: Naming a class with a verb is a bit confusing.

Comment: @DasKrümelmonster I agree with you that using a verb in a class name is confusing.  I think I may have accidentally set up a bad naming convention with my commands.  One that might be hard to get out of without renaming the lot :|

Comment: For me `IsDoodleCommand` sounds correct --since its responsibility is to encapsulate a method-- , but not `GetIsDoodleCommand`; `Get` and `Is` describe the same intention the only difference is : `Is` mean we have only two values but `Get` has many possible values

Answer (score 0):

I would with `IsDoodleCommandResult` .